# Python - Pandas, split long column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=[['a',1],['a',2],['b',3],['b',4],['c',5],['c',6],['d',7],['d',8],['d',9],['e',10]],columns=['key','value'])
  key  value
0   a      1
1   a      2
2   b      3
3   b      4
4   c      5
5   c      6
6   d      7
7   d      8
8   d      9
9   e     10
```

I'm looking for a method that will change the structure based on the key value, like so:

```
   a  b  c  d   e
0  1  3  5  7  10
1  2  4  6  8  10 <- 10 is duplicated
2  2  4  6  9  10 <- 10 is duplicated
```

The result row number is as the longest group count (d in the above example) and the missing values are duplicates of the last available value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with counter column by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), repalce missing values by last non missing ones with `ffill` and last converting all data to `integer`s if necessary:

```
df = df.set_index([df.groupby('key').cumcount(),'key'])['value'].unstack().ffill().astype(int)
```

Another solution with custom lambda function:

```
df = (df.groupby('key')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values))
        .unstack(0)
        .ffill()
        .astype(int))
```

---

```
print (df)
key  a  b  c  d   e
0    1  3  5  7  10
1    2  4  6  8  10
2    2  4  6  9  10
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pivot` , with `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
df.assign(key2=df.groupby('key').cumcount()).pivot('key2','key','value').ffill().astype(int)
Out[214]: 
key   a  b  c  d   e
key2                
0     1  3  5  7  10
1     2  4  6  8  10
2     2  4  6  9  10
```

Comment: What is the key2 for, and how can I remove it?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz key2 is the index name remove it adding rename_axis`df.assign(key2=df.groupby('key').cumcount()).pivot('key2','key','value').ffill().astype(int).rename_axis(None)
`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)